# Error in layout API /v1/apps/{appid}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{resourceid}/sid/{sid}/mode/{mode}/updateLayout

Tags: layout, alibaba-cloud

I have the issue with Agora Cloud API when calling this API:

```
/v1/apps/{appid}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{resourceid}/sid/{sid}/mode/{mode}/updateLayout
```

and pushing the data like this:

```
{
   "uid": "123",
   "cname": "abc",
   "clientRequest": {
       "mixedVideoLayout": 3,
       "backgroundColor": "#FF0000",
       "layoutConfig": [
       {
            "uid": "1",
            "x_axis": 0.1,
            "y_axis": 0.1,
            "width": 0.1,
            "height": 0.1,
            "alpha": 1.0,
            "render_mode": 1
        },
       {
            "uid": "2",
            "x_axis": 0.2,
            "y_axis": 0.2,
            "width": 0.1,
            "height": 0.1,
            "alpha": 1.0,
            "render_mode": 1
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue exists when I am  getting this response:

```
{
 "resourceId": "Cxs-erJeTRb-I-qjn6PK4o8nI9psOgJHxRUrzv2x_B3mMW0eoPtNfWPUcnP7FWl4zloW3lT8JUTHxbtTjRf51wlVM2D2gRa-J5X3z5ekdIV1uWpQ9v0uo9mi2N_mT6jgCvgtQF1AcWlcALSbxM30EsIJsZ3Bm3NH2ZUmg27dvtT4_Hk-d96tn_6IaaPplwfMAgtzQwcPNoMYUtH2oUdzZRLVQ7LDmn22GITa0yoCETvLtkKFzvO6YXzts1SR373VQexRNi1-vdcue1fiDFBVnN8ks2bflTEebo1Gf9EzWfA",
 "sid": "7d027aa32b404af7f21f43852c12e926",
 "code": 404
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The requested resource could not be found."

[Agora Docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms#a-nameupdateaupdates-the-video-mixing-layout)